# Как создавать условия для css в Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

Как правильно задать условия для отображения блоков в Laravel ?
То есть в коде для отображения какой либо информации делается как то так

```php
@if( $item->colection == 0) 
Тут не чего нету
@esle 
Тут что-то было
@endif
```

Можно ли сделать это для таблицы стилей ? У меня есть код который необходимо по-разному отображать на страницах, если быть точнее то он меняется только на главной странице, на всех остальных остается без изменений.

На сколько я понимаю это можно сделать путём проверки URL адреса страницы на которой находится пользователь, или как то иным способом ?

Нашёл код

```php
@if (Request::ulr() === '')
Block 1
@esle
Block 2
@endif
```

Но не понял, мне в сравнение вставить name url страницы, или же ссылку из браузерной строки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как CSS был указан в шапке в тегах `<style>`, то помогло следующие решение
Добавить условие проверки

```php
@if(Route::current(['main.index'])->getName() == 'main.index')
#style_code_here
@else
#style_code_here_2
@endif
```

Таким образом мы проверяем если имя в роутах такое же какое заявлено у нас то выдаем ему первый блок, а если нет, то второй!

Answer (score 1):

Опишите ваши стили а через условие применяйте модификаторы для блока

`$condition = Request::is('/');`

```
<body class="other classes @if($condition) modifier @endif "></body>
```

Или через тернарный оператор

```
<body class="other classes {{ $condition ? 'modifier' : '' }}"></body>
```

В самой таблице стилей можете ниже основного правила описать дополнительно правило

```
.other.classes {
    color: red;
    &.modifier {
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем основном шаблоне сделайте секцию специальную для стилей `@yield('css')`. А потом в шаблоне главной страницы сделайте так:

```
@section('css')
<style>
    //Тут ваши стили
</style>
@endsection
```

Comment: Но таким образом мне придется добавлять в каждое представление, а мне бы просто сделать простую проверку для показа кода в стилях, скорее всего даже уже не стиля,а наименования блока для контентной части

Comment: Нет, только для главной добавьте и все. Не обязательно заполнять или создавать эту секцию во всех представлениях.

Comment: Но у меня получается так что будет работать со стилем только та страница у которой укажу данную секцию, а остальные страницы сайта данную секцию не будут иметь, ну или делать эту секцию с условием проверки, то тогда вариант подойдёт